Apex to Push user onto the Account from the event page
I'm quite new to Apex, Can I write some code so that after an event is logged and saved (I'm guessing would be a trigger) then uses the AccountID to push the user to that accounts page ?

Unfortunately, that's not how triggers work. They can't redirect a user anywhere, because triggers are called without the context of the UI (e.g. it could be an API call, Visualforce page, Lightning Component, etc). If you really wanted to do this, you'd want to override the New Event action with a Lightning Component or Visualforce page.

See Override Standard Actions with Aura Components to get started.
